# pass return value from firefox process to linux shell?

Tags: bash, scripts, firefox, javascript

I want to ask about, how to pass any value from Firefox process to Linux shell?
my case is, I want to create a Linux script tool to calling webpage using Firefox,

after any process in Firefox is done, the Javascript will autoclose the Firefox, I need to capture some value from what Firefox process is done.
is it possible to use the Javascript?

Here is my sample code

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/assembly/

echo $?
```

I want to pass any value from Firefox process to this `var $`?

Comment: Could you please add more details? It is unclear what you are trying to do. Do you what to get web page content?

Comment: If you want to test web page existence from command line, why don't you use _curl_ or _wget_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` always contains the return value from the last executed command. In your example it would be the return value from firefox.

You can save this value in a variable

```
rcode=$?
```

and use it later in your script.

But there are no way to control what value firefox will return in its return-code. That will depend on how it closed. Normal standard is that when a process closes normally it returns 0 (zero). What the meaning of (other) return-codes are, depends on what the programmer has chosen to implement.